# Delete item from Keychain without identifier or reference

Tags: ios, keychain

Is it possible to delete an item from the Keychain if there is no identifier or PersistentRef or other reference available?

I'm not sure it is possible but I want to be sure. The Apple documentation doesn't mention it but that's not always a good indicator.

Deleting all items from the keychain gets the job done but of course that’s not really a great solution.

Comment: How will you find the item if you do not have an identifier?

Comment: @rckoenes That's what I'm afraid of yeah. It doesn't make sense but I was hoping there was some way to delete an item without having a reference.

Comment: :D yes but WHAT item - a random one? any? all?

Comment: @Daij-Djan In some instance we need to remove a public key from the keychain. We could indeed delete the entire keychain but we don't want to do that since we store a lot of other information in there. We didn't store the PersistentRef for that keychain item on disk so we have no reference to that item whatsoever.

Comment: you can SEARCH for an item but you need an attribute to identify it / a name

Comment: @Daij-Djan Ok, that's what I was afraid of :(. Thank you all for your answers!